# Why is there a compile error when calling consturctor?

Tags: c++, constructor, compiler-errors

```
class Normal {
private:
 int v1;
 int v2;
public:
 Normal()
{
 v1 = 0;
 v2 = 0;
}
 Normal (int m, int n); 
};

 Normal::Normal(int m = 5, int n = 5) 
{
 v1 = m;
 v2 = n;
}


int main()
{
 Normal n;
}
```

I get a compile error about overloading but i could'nt figure out why, is the declaration wrong?

Comment: Remove the default values: `Normal::Normal(int m = 5, int n = 5) ` => `Normal::Normal(int m, int n) ` to fix that.

Comment: Instead, can I make  Normal (int m, int n) =>  Normal (int m=5, int n=5) ?

Comment: Sure, you can do that, and ditch the default constructor definition completely instead.

Comment: When you get a compilation error, the first step is to read the error message. It typically tells you what you did wrong.

Comment: yeah sure, but it just say overloading error, that is why I asked here :)

Comment: The compiler can't know whether to call `Normal()` or `Normal(5,5)`, because of those defaults.

Comment: oh, you mean it is not overloaded since there are constant values, right?

Comment: When you define `f(int x=5, int y=5)` you implicitly define `f(int, int)`, `f(int)`, and `f()`, since you provide defaults for both arguments. You can't do this and also define another `f()` elsewhere, since that conflicts with the other definition.

Comment: thank you I got it @chi